# Mysql : Query with LIKE on varbinary column from java

Tags: java, mysql

Lets say I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (col varbinary(100));
```

Now I would like to do a "LIKE" query on this column using java, something like this -

```
String query="SELECT * from T WHERE col LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query); // Assuming I already have connection object
byte[] prefixBytes = somePrefixBytesIWouldLikeToSearchFor;
String likeString = new String(bytes) + "%";
st.setString(1, likeString);
st.executeQuery();
```

Is that right way to go about it? If not, what is the correct way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use string concat inside sql command  eg:

```
String query="SELECT * from T WHERE col LIKE concat(?, '%')";
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query); // Assuming I already have connection object
byte[] prefixBytes = somePrefixBytesIWouldLikeToSearchFor;
String likeString = new String(bytes)
st.setBytes(1,  bytes);
st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I used your suggestion with small modification which works perfectly. This is what I ended up doing:

     String query="SELECT * from T WHERE col LIKE concat(?, '%')";
     PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     byte[] prefixBytes = somePrefixBytesIWouldLikeToSearchFor;
     st.setBytes(1, bytes);
     st. executeQuery();